# Minimize sum of maximum dot product between unit vectors

Tags: geometry, optimization, inner-products, spheres, constraints

Let $\mathbb{S}_{d-1}$ denote the unit [$(d-1)$-sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere). Let
\begin{align}
    f(d, n) = \operatorname*{argmin}_{x \in (\mathbb{S}_{d-1})^n} \sum_{i \in n} \max_{j \in n - \{i\}} x_i \cdot x_j
\end{align}

Let $g(d, n)$ be the corresponding minimum value. What is known about $f$ and $g$? Do they have a name in the literature? Are the following solutions correct? Are other solution classes known?

| $d$ | $n$ | $f(d,n)$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $1$ | $n$ | $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ on one point and $\lceil n/2 \rceil$ on the other |
| $2$ | $n$ | vertices of a [regular $n$-gon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon) |
| $d$ | $n \leq d+1$ | vertices of a regular $(n-1)$-[simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex) |
| $3$ | $5$ | vertices of a [triangular bipyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_bipyramid) |
| $3$ | $6$ | vertices of a regular [octahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedron) |
| $3$ | $8$ | vertices of a uniform [square antiprism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_antiprism) |
| $3$ | $12$ | vertices of a regular [icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedron) |

See the [Thomson problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem) and [spherical codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_code) for related problems. These questions might have relevant information:

- [Minimizing the maximum dot product among k unit vectors in an n-dimensional space](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14736/minimizing-the-maximum-dot-product-among-k-unit-vectors-in-an-n-dimensional-spac)
- [Is the Fibonacci lattice the very best way to evenly distribute N points on a sphere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358046/is-the-fibonacci-lattice-the-very-best-way-to-evenly-distribute-n-points-on-a-sp)
- [Evenly distributing n points on a sphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600801/evenly-distributing-n-points-on-a-sphere)